# Github action job fire when previous job skipped

Tags: github-actions

While setting up my GitHub action to build and deploy my apps, I'm running into the following issue.

I want to deploy my web app under the following conditions below. However, whenever `deploy-api` and `deploy-sync` skip `deploy-web` is also skipped. I figured that my if condition would catch that case and still run `deploy-web` but it isn't. Feels like I'm missing something obvious but can't identify it.

```
deploy-web:
  name: Deploy Web
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  needs: [build-and-publish-web, deploy-api, deploy-sync]
  if: |
    needs.build-and-publish-web.result == 'success' &&
    (needs.deploy-api.result == 'success' || needs.deploy-api.result == 'skipped') &&
    (needs.deploy-sync.result == 'success' || needs.deploy-sync.result == 'skipped')
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It seems like you encounter this [issue - Job-level "if" condition not evaluated correctly if job in "needs" property is skipped](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/491#issuecomment-850884422).

Please try with always expression:

```yaml
deploy-web:
  name: Deploy Web
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  needs: [build-and-publish-web, deploy-api, deploy-sync]
  if: |
    always() &&
    needs.build-and-publish-web.result == 'success' &&
    (needs.deploy-api.result == 'success' || needs.deploy-api.result == 'skipped') &&
    (needs.deploy-sync.result == 'success' || needs.deploy-sync.result == 'skipped')
```

Not specific to the original question but if all you care about is making sure there are no failures, `needs.*.result` provides wildcard behavior that prevents you from having to manually check each step:

```
  if: |
    always() &&
    !contains(needs.*.result, 'failure') &&
    !contains(needs.*.result, 'cancelled')
```

Comment: Surprised I didn't come across that discussion already. Thanks for linking it. Definitely a system that could use some love. This changed got everything working for me! Thanks!

Comment: Nice solution, but the problem is that jobs depending on `deploy-web` still are skipped and then you end up adding `always()` everywhere :(

Comment: Another problem with `always()` used in jobs is that the job cannot be cancelled (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/canceling-a-workflow#steps-github-takes-to-cancel-a-workflow-run)

Comment: I like `${{ always() && !failed() && !cancelled() }}`

Comment: I got `Unrecognized function: 'failed'` when I used `if: ${{ always() && !failed() && !cancelled() }}`...

Comment: @kgutwin it should be `failure()`

Comment: `contains` doesn't seem to be working. In my case, I want my job to run if _any_ of the previous dependencies succeeded. I tried: 

`always() && !cancelled() && contains(needs.*.result, 'success')` but this does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18):

I prefer a more concise condition, but if your conditions are complex you may need a more complex solution as in the accepted answer:

```
needs: [compute_version_tag, bump_version]
if: ${{ always() && !failure() && !cancelled() }} # when none of the needed jobs fail or are cancelled (skipped or successful jobs are ok).
```

Beware that `!cancelled()` is required to be able to cancel jobs having `always()` in the if condition.

Comment: `${{ }}` no longer required in `if:` expressions, so just `if: always() && !failure() && !cancelled()`

Comment: Even terser: `if: ${{ !(failure() || cancelled()) }}`